# First time to install python, and test in git bash

Tags: python, git-bash

OS : Windows 10

It is the first time to install python.

I want to run python on git bash.

I haven't used python or git bash before.

1. I installed portable git.
   C:\Users\ *username* \Desktop\PortableGit

[image]

2. I created a small file named ib in Portable git folder, whose content is

[image: enter code here]

3. I installed python
   C:\Users\ *username* \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310

[image]

4. Run git-bash.exe in portable git folder,
   and check the version of python, and run ib.

   python --version
   ./ib

[image]

It says no such file or directory. The code ./ib didn't work. Can you teach me?

If you need more information, you can ask me!(tasks/screenshots)

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` show? You need to add the python executable to the path in order to run it from any sub directory.

Comment: Note: this has nothing to do with Git. Git-bash is a port of bash to Windows, so that you can *use* Git on Windows, but is not itself Git or part *of* Git. It's just packaged *with* versions of Git for Windows (because Git needs a POSIX-compatible shell, and the port of bash to Windows known as "git-bash" is that shell).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the directory which contains the python executable to the `PATH` variable. One way to do this is to edit `.bashrc` in your home directory and add a line similar to

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/python
```

replacing `/path/to/python` with the directory where `python3` is located.

Comment: that would usually be ```/usr/bin/```

Comment: @Loïc According to the screenshots from the OP, it is somewhere else in this particular case. This isn't surprising since this is on a Windows machine with mingw.